# Is it possible to print a custom message after a successful pip package installation from PyPI?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

I want to log a custom message to my users after they install my package via pip:
`pip install my-package`

I tried to add a print statement to `setup.py`.

running `pip install -v my-package` or `pip install my-package` didn't print it.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: You could customize the `install` step in your setup.py and write to stdout there. However you will only see these messages when using `pip ... -v`. Is that what you want/acceptable?

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to log a custom message to users when they install a package via pip. However, you can use the post_install_message argument in the setup.py file to set a message that will be printed during the installation. For example:

```
setup(
    ...
    post_install_message="Thanks for installing my-package!",
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Unfortunately, this didn't print the message anywhere, using -v and without.

Comment: This answer does not seem true at all to me.